# "cataloginventory/stock_item_api" set no data on update

Tags: api, ce-1.8.1.0, stock, inventory, stock-status

I try to create over 4,000 products in a demostore. **`catalog/product_api`** returns the id of the created product ... all fine. Then i call **`catalog/product_attribute_media_api`** with the id of the created product to create a image by base64-content. Even this works too. At the last i try to call **`cataloginventory/stock_item_api`** as update. It's run, i get as result ***`true`***, but there is no data visible in the database / adminpanel.

Here the script part:

```
$arrCurrentStockData = array(
    'qty' => '100',
    'is_in_stock ' => 1,
    'manage_stock ' => 1,
    'use_config_manage_stock' => 0,
    'min_qty' => 1,
    'use_config_min_qty ' => 1,
    'min_sale_qty' => 1,
    'use_config_min_sale_qty' => 1,
    'max_sale_qty' => 10,
    'use_config_max_sale_qty' => 1,
    'is_qty_decimal' => 0,
    'backorders' => 1,
    'use_config_backorders' => 1,
    'notify_stock_qty' => 10,
    'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 1
);
var_dump(Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item_api')->update($intProductID,$arrCurrentStockData));
```

I tried to to this with the regular class **`cataloginventory/stock_item`** - no data. Tried to set data in the creat-call from the product as **`stock_data`** - no data.

I have a clean local installation (1.8.1) without 3rd-party-extensions. What's wrong? Has Anybody a tip? Even now, many , many thanks!

### Edit

If i open a product in adminpanel and save it, then write the system data to the `cataloginventory_stock_item`-table - funny!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by run a api-request (soap) like this:

```
$soapMulticalls = array();

$arrProductsExists = $soap->call($soapSession, 'catalog_product.list');

foreach($arrProductsExists as $arrProduct) {

    $soapMulticallDataItem = array(
        'catalog_product.update',
        array(
            $arrProduct['product_id'],
            array(
                'stock_data' => array(
                    'qty' => '999',
                    'is_in_stock' => 1,
                    'manage_stock' => 1,
                    'backorders' => 0,
                    'use_config_backorders' => 0,
                    'use_config_manage_stock' => 1
                )
            )
        )
    );

    array_push($soapMulticalls, $soapMulticallDataItem);
}
if (count($soapMulticalls) > 0) {
    var_dump($soap->multiCall($soapSession, $soapMulticalls));
}
```

That's not the perfect way. But: it's work.